# Baggage handling and transit at Tokyo Narita

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, luggage, japan

I am an Indian passport holder and will be traveling from Calgary (YYC) to Mumbai with a transit at Narita with a 21 hour layover.
1. Will I be able to get a transit visa on arrival or is it essential to get it before travel?
2. Will my baggage be checked right through with such an overnight layover and regardless of whether I want to stay in a nearby hotel during the layover?

Comment: You’ve omitted some essential information such as your residence status in Canada, whether your flight booking is on a single ticket.

Comment: I live in India but my wife and I will be visiting my daughter's family in Calgary on a visitors visa. It is a single ticket but it is a long, overnight layover.